# Laravel: Logging messages generated by "error_log(...)" to terminal, while running app in Apache server

Tags: php, laravel, apache, lamp, linux-mint

The issue is this one:

When I run a Laravel app from PHP server, that's it, with `php artisan serve`, I could see every message generated by "error_log(...)" printed in the terminal, like this:

[image: php artisan serve]

However, while trying to achieve something similar but in Apache server (instead of PHP server) , I've found some troubles.

By running the `phpinfo();`function within a test file, I'm getting the line:

> **Loaded Configuration File**  | /etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini

Then, by adding the line `error_log = /home/leandro/log/php_errors.log`  to that file, and then restarting Apache, I could achieve a similar result by doing in the console:
 `tail -n 0 -f /home/leandro/log/php_errors.log`

Despite this works, this solution implies a lot of disk I/O operations and so on, an ugly performance and potential harm to the disk at long term.

I've tried to replace the mentioned line in my "php.ini" to `error_log = /dev/stderr` and then the commands:
  `tail -f /dev/stderr` and `cat /dev/stderr` in the terminal, but none of them is working, even with the `sudo` prefix.

Anyone has an idea of how to achieve the result I want to?

If there's more information needed, or something that it isn't well understood, please let me know.

Thanks a lot!
Leandro